# Can I write an Excel macro to find product info based on a SKU?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

My coworker wants to create an invoice template in Excel 2007. In column 1, he wants to be able to put in a SKU like '000293954'[1], and when he hits tab, have the other columns fill in a matching description and price. There would be a bunch of different SKUs and information.

Has anybody done this type of thing with a macro before? Any advice?

(I have programming experience with Javascript, PHP, and Ruby, but have never written a macro.)

[1] *The input wouldn't be typed - he'd use a wedge barcode scanner that inputs just like it was typed. Not that it matters for this question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where's your list of products?  In another Excel sheet?  If so, the best course would be using VLOOKUP to get the information.  Say you enter SKUs in A10:A20. You could get the product name in B10 like

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A10,ProductList!A1:G1000,2,FALSE),"Product Not Found")
```

I've made a lot of assumptions here.  Your products are on a sheet in the same workbook named ProductList.  The products on ProductList are in A1:G1000 (a named range would be better).

Comment: Great! This does the trick. (I got a bit of help from here, too: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)